# ADFS Single Sign On with ReactJS (Frontend) /.Net Core Web API (Backend)

Tags: reactjs, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, asp.net-core-3.1, adfs4.0

We are having react app as frontend application and .NET Core Web API as Back end application. Our client requirement is to integrate ADFS SSO. Our Client is already having On-Premises ADFS running in their windows server 2016.

After some googling I have following questions raised up in my mind.

1.) Based on my analysis, ADFS is supporting following sign-in protocols (SAML 2.0, WS-Federation & OAuth). For our application setup(React/.NET Core Web API), which protocol, we should use?

2.) Our client is asking us to use for SAML2.0. Is SAML 2.0 Protocol can be used for our application architecture (React/.NET Core Web API)?

3.) To configure our application in On-Premises ADFS, I saw following options (Relying Party Trust and Application Groups). For our application architecture, which one should be used?

Please help me with your thoughts. I am not able to take any concrete decision on the above questions since I am new to the ADFS SSO. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.